# Lenovo Professional Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo not working in ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, lenovo

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I recently acquired a Lenovo Professional Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo (part number 4X30H56796).
I can successfully pair keyboard and mouse. Mouse works fine. 
On the keyboard the only keys that respond are the calculator, sound, and windows. All other keys do not work.

Can anyone advise on how to make this keyboard work?

Comment: We have this problem as well with ubuntu 17.04. No fix so far :(. It seems that the keyboard has no 'event codes' for letters or any non-special buttons: https://pastebin.com/rXYy8WhV . The output of the second 'showkey' command shows the result of mashing some buttons on the keyboard: only the windows key was detected.

Answer (score 1):

This is finally fixed! I test it in Ubuntu 18.04 kernel: 4.15.0-64, Ubuntu 18.04.3 kernel: 5.0.0-29.

The keyboard and mouse seems to work fine with no issues! I had to disable a workaround used to make it work! https://github.com/y-trudeau/linux_lenovo_ultraslim_plus

It was also fixed in Fedora 30 according to this report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1625415

Old answer:

There is a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1771431

The bug is still present in the latest Ubuntu version (18.04 bionic beaver) with stable kernel.

It's also reported by people from Linux Mint, Fedora and others.

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Professional-Wireless-Keyboard-not-working-on-Linux/td-p/3726486

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2378862

[Lenovo Professional Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo not working in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897729/lenovo-professional-wireless-keyboard-and-mouse-combo-not-working-in-ubuntu)

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=260093&sid=20a073d5dd8abb1b7f23be608d7fdfd7

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377830/linux-hid-driver-for-primax-wireless-keyboards/

Possible workaround: https://github.com/y-trudeau/linux_lenovo_ultraslim_plus

Answer (score 0):

It's now working on Ubuntu 18.04.4 with kernel 4.15.0-91 without the need for the fix provided in https://github.com/y-trudeau/linux_lenovo_ultraslim_plus