# Wireless keyboard not working with Ubuntu 18.04 Live USB

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I created a Live USB with Ubunbtu 18.04 on it so I can look into dual booting on a Windows 10 PC.

When I boot Ubuntu from USB, I can't get my wireless keyboards to work.  They both work on Windows, so there is no battery issue.  They both use a wireless USB dongle.  The wireless mouse with one of them works fine.

I used a wired keyboard to install xserver-xorg-input-all using `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`, but the wireless keyboards still won't work

Is there anything else anyone can suggest that I try ?

Edit:

Output from `lsusb` is as follows -

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0781:556b SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 17ef:60a9 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0821 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046e:550f Behavior Tech. Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046e:5411 Behavior Tech. Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The SanDisk device is the Live Usb and Lenovo is the keyboard/mouse.
The keyboard/mouse are as supplied with the PC and are Lenovo. My alternative set with the same symptoms is by Microsoft.

Comment: What keyboard model(s) are we talking about? If they're connected through a wireless USB dongle can you please connect it/them, run `lsusb` and add the output to your question? If it's via Bluetooth can you please add the output of `rfkill list`? THanks.

Comment: If it's USB it really should work out of the box, can you add the VID/PID of the keyboard

Comment: @jrtapsell - Can you tell me what you mean by VID/PID of the keyboard ?

Comment: @DavidFoerster - One of the keyboard/mouse combos is Microsoft and the other is Lenovo. They both have the same sympton. I'll get the 'lsusb' output and attach to the question shortly.

Comment: Vendor ID, Product ID, lsusb should give you them

Comment: @xiota - the only other USB devices are the wired keyboard that I need to use temporarily and the live USB I'm  using. I can't unplug either of them and still use the system. I've already done the xorg-input-all thing using apt-get, not sure what putting 'aptitude' in there will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update January 2, 2022

This bug has been fixed according to the bug report: [Lenovo Essential Wireless Keyboard doesn't works (Primax Electronics manufacturer) #36](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1771431) which states:

> Julian Alarcon (julian-alarcon) wrote on 2019-09-19:          #36
>
> This is finally fixed! I test it in Ubuntu 18.04 kernel: 4.15.0-64, Ubuntu 18.04.3 kernel: 5.0.0-29.
>
> The keyboard and mouse seems to work fine with no issues! I had to disable a workaround used to make it work! https://github.com/y-trudeau/linux_lenovo_ultraslim_plus

## Original post

The original post is shown below for historical purposes.

### Extensive history to this problem

You are not alone. Someone in [Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2378862) has reported:

> Re: Lenovo Essential Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo doesn't work
>
> I just reported this bug:
> [Lenovo Essential Wireless Keyboard doesn't works (Primax Electronics manufacturer)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1771431)
>
> The bug is still present in the latest Ubuntu version (18.04 bionic beaver) with stable kernel.
>
> It's also reported by people from Linux Mint, Fedora and others.
>
> - [Professional Wireless Keyboard not working on Linux](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Professional-Wireless-Keyboard-not-working-on-Linux/td-p/3726486)
> - [Lenovo Essential Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo doesn't work](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2378862)
> - [Lenovo Professional Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo not working in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897729/lenovo-professional-wireless-keyboard-and-mouse-combo-not-working-in-ubuntu)
> - [Wireless keyboard Lenovo doesn't work properly](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=260093&sid=20a073d5dd8abb1b7f23be608d7fdfd7)
> - [Linux HID driver for Primax wireless keyboards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377830/linux-hid-driver-for-primax-wireless-keyboards/)

#### Possible workarounds

Although the bug has been confirmed by the Ubuntu Team, no one has been assigned to fixing it yet. In the meantime there are two workarounds:

- [GitHub - y-trudeau /
  linux_lenovo_ultraslim_plus](https://github.com/y-trudeau/linux_lenovo_ultraslim_plus)
- [Linux HID driver for Primax wireless keyboards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402288/200094)

Comment: Although his doesn't solve my problem as it isn't solvable yet it does give me some options to work round the issue. I asked for suggestions for what else to try and this certainly provides some. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried the Lenovo fix from WinEunuuchs2Unix's answer and it did not work, you might want to try this modified fix that I made for another Primax (HP brand) wireless keyboard + mouse combo with similar problems:

https://github.com/JohnJohanssonChalmers/hp_wireless_keyboard

I have seen several reports of these types of problems with Primax keyboards that could not be solved with the Lenovo fix. I suspect that my modified fix might also wok for some non-HP keyboards.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at this tomorrow when I'm at home.

Comment: @jkej I've updated my answer and the bug has been fixed. Thanks for linking another possible solution though.