# Ubuntu 20.04 Mouse and Keyboard Not Working

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

Mouse works up the the point of the login screen, then the cursor stops at the center and it and the keyboard will not work. It was working, then suddenly it wasn’t while the same mouse and keyboard are functional on a different PC under Windows so clearly not a problem with them. The mouse and keyboard are wireless USB and are the only ones I have so what can I do to get it functional again?

Answer (score 2):

At first use `lsusb` to be sure if the device is connected.
If you find its connected successfully.

Then use
`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all` in terminal.

It should install the input services needed.
May need a system reboot after installation.
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040279/wireless-keyboard-not-working-with-ubuntu-18-04-live-usb) forum might help you if you are still stuck.