# mouse and keyboard not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, mouse, login-screen

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. I just got this box (HP Z220 Workstation) back from a student who was using it successfully. However, when I boot, my mouse and keyboard are not working at login.

The machine is on my network (wired), so I can ssh in. I see both devices in lsusb. I am able to boot to GRUB and go into recovery mode, so the keyboard is working. I have tried multiple ports and keyboards and mice.

Several pages have suggested doing updates/upgrades, including
`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`
and I have tried this, to no avail.

I'm at a loss of what to do next. I have reviewed these questions:

- [Keyboard + Mouse not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426307/keyboard-mouse-not-working)
- [Ubuntu 20.04 Mouse and Keyboard Not Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349862/ubuntu-20-04-mouse-and-keyboard-not-working)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 keyboard and mouse not working at login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135717/ubuntu-18-04-keyboard-and-mouse-not-working-at-login-screen)

Per RonJohn's questions below, kb works in UEFI, but AFAIK there's no way to tell about the mouse. As I wrote, I've tried multiple kbs and mice, but here's what lsusb says right now:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0e6a:02c0 Megawin Technology Co., Ltd Defender Gaming Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17ef:602e Lenovo USB Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

OK, figured it out... by uninstalling the desktop entirely, I was at the tty login prompt and I got error "USB Device Not Authorized for usage".

Turns out that usbguard was installed and configured to permanently autoblock any USB device that was hot-plugged after booting. I guess I connected the first KB and mouse after booting, and then I swapped other KB and mice while running.

Anyway, I don't need usbguard, so I uninstalled that and then just reinstalled Gnome.

Comment: What does `lsusb` say?  Do the kb and mouse work in UEFI?

Comment: @RonJohn, couldn't fit everything here so I added it to the original question.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Always add the new information in your question when we ask you for clarifications. Best of luck!

Comment: "kb works in UEFI, but AFAIK there's no way to tell about the mouse."  Mice work in Gigabyte's UEFI "bios" manager.  Maybe they also work in Dell's.

Comment: It's apparent that Linux detects the "Lenovo USB Optical Mouse".  What if you turn it off and turn it back on?

Comment: @RonJohn the issue was usbguard, which I didn't know about. Rebooting, even with the devices attached, didn't help. I really appreciate your help, though!

Comment: I should have known that schools (and businesses) implement something like that.  Heck, my company-provided laptop can *only* write encrypted files to thumb drives.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but I dont have `usbguard` installed. Any suggestion?

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram, sorry, wish I had. I am assuming that you already ran through the linked questions and tried what worked there.

Comment: @Joshua Yes, none of them worked. My issue was with `tlp`. I stopped that service and now USB is working normal